# Prepared statement to select data in php

Tags: php

I am trying to select data from database without condition . How to display the name of records from database ? So far , I tried this !

```
<div class="well"><form method="post" >
     <div class="form-check">
    <?php
    $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','icac_database');
    $seq = 'SELECT adr_name,adr_id FROM `adr` ';
    $stmt = $con->prepare($seq);
    //$stmt->bind_param('ss',$adr_name,$adr_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($adr_name,$adr_id);
    while($stmt->fetch() ) { 
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" class="form-check-input" id="type">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="contin"><?php $adr_name; ?> </label>   

    <?php  }?>
    </div>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" name="choose" value="submit"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: If your table contains more than one record you need to give your `checkbox`es different `name`s, or you will not be able to distinguish them. Likewise for your `for="contin"` (for which I do not see a corresponding `id`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to `echo` your variable :

```
<?php echo $adr_name; ?>
```

Comment: I did an echo inside while loop

Comment: @MoudiNasrallah Sorry, I don't see it in your code. I just see `<?php $adr_name; ?>`. That will not write your variable content.

Comment: where should I do it ?

Comment: @MoudiNasrallah Replace `<?php $adr_name; ?>` by `<?php echo $adr_name; ?>` in you while loop.

Comment: @MoudiNasrallah It's an usual error :) If you don't see something, check that for the next time :)

Comment: Thankyou my friend